# onActivityResult() is not firing in my Android application

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I am at a loss for what the problem is, I have read pretty much every single related question but am stumped as to what my problem could be, the Activity runs fine and it closes on the `finish()` method, but nothing is done in my MainActivity class. I made sure that my manifest does not call `noHistory` and `singleton` activity. I placed a few toasts and a text set but none of them are being called. Here is my code implementation:

On MainActivity:

```
Intent placeShips = new Intent(this, SetShips.class); //MainActivity.this works too
startActivityForResult(placeShips, RESULT_OK);
```

.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    newGame.setText("PLS ");  //these aren't being called either
    toast("PLS");
}
```

On called Activity:
(Please note the buttons work fine)

```
    setShips.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish(); //return to main activity, giving intent with stored player information
        }
    });
```

Further notes; toasts are shown correctly on the `setShips` button listener, however, nothing passes back to the `onActivityResult` method, as explained, not even toasts show. Am I missing something else?

Comment: You don't need to call `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`. Is the `onActivityResult` method in your `SetShips` class?

Comment: Please use other name of request code `RESULT_OK`. It is duplicated.

Comment: It might be a silly question, but are you using `startActivityForResult` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't properly set your request code. You need to do:

```
static final int YOUR_CODE = 1; 
Intent placeShips = new Intent(this, SetShips.class); //MainActivity.this works too
startActivityForResult(placeShips, YOUR_CODE);
```

Then you can do:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == YOUR_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    newGame.setText("PLS ");  //these aren't being called either
    toast("PLS");
}
```

Comment: But what is the problem in sending `RESULT_OK` as `requestCode`?

Comment: This was it, thank you tons. For some reason I thought `RESULT_OK` was global var

Comment: @RaviRupareliya You need to set your own request code. The RESULT_OKAY is a variable used by the SDK.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai yes i agree with you, but value should be integer and `RESULT_OK` is a global int variable, so why can't we use it?

Answer (score 0):

Your result code sould be like this

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_OK && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```